# Firebase firestore structure

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My current database approach looks like this:

[image]

Now when I stream products, I want for every product the subcollections (images, prices, sizes).
What will be the best idea to fetch this in a stream, without using a lot of reads? I heard of something like a collection group.

Or should I just store every subcollection in the main collection?

Comment: Every document you fetch in the client will cost 1 read.  You can't change that cost at all, no matter how you perform the queries or organize the documents.  The only way to reduce the number of reads is to reduce the number of documents you actually get from your queries.

Comment: I mean the read per product. When I store all my data in the document not seperated in subcollection I have less reads

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I stream products, I want for every product the subcollections (images, prices, sizes). What will be the best idea to fetch this in a stream, without using a lot of reads. I heard of something like collection group.

How collection group query work just read all documents with same collection name, So if you run a collection group query without `.where .limit etc` for images, You will read all documents in every images collection.

In this case you have different collection name, So you will need 4 listener, `products, images(Collection group), prices(Collection group), sizes(Collection group),` then put associated data together on client.

> Or should I just store every subcollection in the main collection ?

It's not easy to say which approach is better, Firestore charge per document, If you want to minimize cost of reads, Maybe it make sense, But notice that the maximum size for a document is 1MB, Also if you use `.get` in rules also charges.

Comment: Oh man. Then I think, I will store all data in the document, that should be enough. Then I need to build a little admin page. Where I can easily manage all data.

Answer (score 0):

As @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, there is no way in which you can change the way Firestore is billing us. You'll always have to pay a read operation for each document you get. If the images, prices, and sizes are not too large, then you can add all that information inside the product document. This means that you'll don't have to perform additional reads to get that data. You'll always have that data available inside the product document (object). This technique will work **only** as long as the details of the product will stay below the [maximum limitation of 1 Mib](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits).

Another optimization in your case might be to add all the products that correspond to a category in a single document. That will also work only as long as you stay below the maximum limit.

Another important thing would be to use [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) when you read multiple documents. This means that you have to load the data in smaller chunks. This technique will reduce the number of reads you perform.

A [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) will only help if you need to read documents from multiple collections or subcollections that have the same name. However, this feature will not reduce the number of reads. The billing is the same also in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I think I will make everything in the document itself. i will later put every info in the document to test if everything mathes. Can I see how big my document is ?

Comment: You can [calculate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) that yourself.

Comment: I calculated really big. With like 25 Images. And 40 sizes. Which is really big calc. I coming to like max 50.000 bytes. So I am storing everything in one doc

Comment: Hey Phil. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?